# Deleting app backups of iTunes from Mac

Tags: itunes, applications, backup, storage

I have few space remained on my MacBook Air. When I check `Storage` and click on `Manage`, this is what I saw:
[image]

iTunes is using up 6 GB of space and these are apps from my phone. And the worst part is there are some apps which are not used any more and uninstalled years ago. How can I get this space back?

iTunes version: 12.6.0.100

Computer's configuration: macOS Sierra 10.12.4
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to your iTunes library location using Finder (by default it is in `~/Music/iTunes`), then open the `iTunes Media/Mobile Applications` folder and delete the apps you wish.

Comment: I have found "Mobile Applications" in "~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media"

Comment: @Nuri Apologies for the mistake and thanks for the clarification.